# Form with a jQuery dialog inside does not submit

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui

I have a small form that contains a jQuery UI dialog to ask for additional information if a particular checkbox is checked. The dialog opens and contains 2 additional checkboxes.

The problem is when the form is submitted the 2 checkboxes in the dialog do not get submitted with the rest of the form. From what I can tell when jQuery renders the dialog, it actually renders it outside the closing form tag, causing the checkboxes to not be part of the form anymore.

I have tried things like:

```
$("#dialog-form").parent().appendTo($("#ContactSpeakerForm:first"));
```

But have not come up with a good solution.

Here is my js:

```
$(function() {

    var eventReg = $('#dialog-form').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $('#Confirmed').click(function() {
        if($('#Confirmed').attr('checked')) {
            eventReg.dialog("open");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the html:

```
<form id="ContactSpeakerForm" name="ContactSpeakerForm" action="/contacts/add-contact-speaker/id/3420" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="" id="ID">
    <input type="hidden" name="Contact_ID" value="3420" id="Contact_ID">    

    <div class="page_panel_table">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" class="form_label">Confirmed:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Confirmed" id="Confirmed" value="1">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>        
    </div>

    <div id="dialog-form" style="display:none;" title="Speaker Event Registration">
        <input type="checkbox" name="RegisterForEvent" id="RegisterForEvent" value="1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="RegisterForDinner" id="RegisterForDinner" value="1">
    </div>
</form>
```

Anyone know a good solution?

Comment: critical issue is that a dialog gets appended to body to make it easier to manage positioning... so it gets removed from your form

Comment: @charlietfl: yes this is the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After setting up your dialog, use:

```
eventReg.closest('div.ui-dialog').appendTo('#ContactSpeakerForm');
```

There are two key things here.  First, you run this after the widget has had a chance to initialize and change the mark up.  Second, you remove the dependence on the direct parent/child relationship.

Comment: Thank you this works! But still have a bad side effect. I am setting one of the checkboxes in the dialog to be checked by default, and if the dialog is never opened then values do not get submitted in the form. Any ideas?

Comment: @MichaelIrey they should always be submitted if they are checked.  They won't be submitted if they are not checked.  I don't see where you are setting one to checked by default so if the dialog isn't opened, neither will be submitted.

Comment: Thank you for all your great input. For some reason when I try have this `eventReg.closest('div.ui-dialog').appendTo('#ContactSpeakerForm');` It moves it into the form alright, but it also moves it behind the overlay... so I cant even click on it. Any ideas?

Comment: I found I had conflicting z-index making the modal go behind the overlay

Comment: This is old thread, I have same issue. I have applied your solution but i am getting "eventReg is not defined" error. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: @Anjum `eventReg` is what the OP named the variable holding his dialog.  You'll need to change that to the variable you are assigning the dialog to.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it tomorrow and will let u know.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone who have the same issue there is a newer and simpler solution: an "appendTo" option has been introduced in jQuery UI 1.10.0

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    appendTo: "#ContactSpeakerForm"
    ....
});
```